# MFC/C++ Bring window to top no longer works

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a 32-bit application built on MFC/C++.  It was ported from Visual C++ (6.0) to Studio 2015.

The application needs to come to the top when new data appears.  On a couple of my customer systems the window does not come to the front as another application seems to want to stay on top.  This code (in MainFrm.cpp) was working fine prior to the 2015 port (same "topmost" source code).

...

```
HWND hCurrWnd;
int iMyTID;
int iCurrTID;

hCurrWnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();
iMyTID   = GetCurrentThreadId();
iCurrTID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurrWnd,0);

::AttachThreadInput(iCurrTID, iMyTID, TRUE);
::SetWindowPos(m_hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
::SetWindowPos(m_hWnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
::SetForegroundWindow(m_hWnd);
::SetFocus(m_hWnd);
::SetActiveWindow(m_hWnd);
::AttachThreadInput(iCurrTID, iMyTID, FALSE);
```

...

Is there another, more robust method for forcing a window to the top in MFC?

Comment: Have a read of [Old New Thing - How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253)  In summary - if you could write code to force your window to the top; what happens if another application has exactly the same code?  Who wins?

Comment: I understand the dilemma posed in the article.  It's not a persistent topmost that I'm going for.  In fact, I can manually make my app topmost by clicking on it in the taskbar or Alt-Tabbing to it.  Thus, I'm looking for a programmatic way of doing that.  The real question is "why did this stop working when porting the VC++ (6.0) to Studio 2015 and the associated 2015 runtime?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080801-00/?p=21393